# How to Edit Joomla Full HTML

Tags: joomla-3.x

[image: Full HTML]

How Do I edit full HTML like blogspot ? Starting from first HTML until end of it. I want to edit HTML manually . The template manager show it part by part 
.. Joomla 3.6.5 . I've purchased template from Rockettheme and want to edit overall its content . Thank You ..

Comment: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/19322/120 is a similar question.

Comment: Here is a list with links to where you can learn more about Joomla: [**Beginner Tutorials**](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16529/joomla-beginner-tutorials-how-to-start-with-joomla)

Answer (score 1):

Joomla is a content management system and the page code is assembled from several different sources depending on the extensions enabled for the particular page such as the template and the component and any plugins or modules.

This makes it difficult to edit the code directly and reliably.

You can use template overrides and other methods to override the default code but you need to know what you are doing.

I suggest you start reading some of the documentation before making changes that could easily be overwritten by Joomla or third party extension updates in future.

See https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/19338/120 for more information.

Comment: Thank you .. I guest I have to learn more about overriding a template ..